# Quarkus Rest Client never timeouts

Tags: rest-client, quarkus

The rest client never times out. After multiple requests, quarkus stops serving new requests.
Also tried
.../mp-rest/connectTimeout=5000
.../mp-rest/readTimeout=5000
but with no luck.

The interface looks like

```
package org.acme;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@RegisterRestClient
public interface ExampleClient {

@GET
@Path("/test")
    String test();
}
```

the service like

```
package org.acme;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RestClient;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class ExampleResource {

    @Inject
    @RestClient
    ExampleClient exampleClient;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        return exampleClient.test();
    }
}
```

and the application.properties file like

```
org.acme.ExampleClient/mp-rest/url=http://localhost:8081
org.acme.ExampleClient/mp-rest/connectTimeout=5000
org.acme.ExampleClient/mp-rest/readTimeout=5000
```

In order to test, call http://localhost:8080/hello and point localhost:8081 to a service in debug mode with a breakpoint.

I have tested on quarkus 0.22 and 0.23.2.

Comment: Can you provide some more information such as the version of Quarkus and maybe some example code?

Comment: Hi Ken, updated the info. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not likely to fix it, but can you try adding ```@Path("/")``` to the interface definition?

Comment: So in making a list of the TCK tests that are excluded and what needs fixing, it looks like timeout is one of the currently skipped tests (https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/tcks/microprofile-rest-client/tck-suite.xml#L22) Will be looking to implement shortly

Answer (score 2):

This problem is now resolved in 0.27 that came out a couple of days ago